# How would I modify this inequalities so Mathematica will confirm them?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, expression

I get lots of conditions like this:

```
a (b c - (-1 + a) d (c + f g)) h > (-1 + a) i (b + a  j ) g
```

I have following assumptions all variables are real and greater 0, a is also smaller 1, in Mathematica:

```
$Assumptions = {a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i, j} \[Element] 
   Reals && {a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i, j} > 0 && 0 < a < 1
```

Despite a few simple cases Reduce produces following output:

> A very large output was generated. Here is a sample of it:
>   (a | b | c | d | f | i) [Element] 
>     Reals && ((j < 0 && (<<1>>)) || (j == 0 && (<<1>>)) || (j > 
>         0 && (<<1>>)))

I wonder how would I need to input it to evaluate to true or false.

---

Manually in this case it must be true:

- rewrite `-1+a` to `-(1-a)`

  a (b c + (1 - a) d (c + f g)) h > -(1 - a) i (b + a  j ) g
- all to left side:

  a (b c + (1 - a) d (c + f g)) h+ (1 - a) i (b + a  j ) g > 0
- since (1-a)>0 and all other variables >0 the left side is the sum of products of variables that are all >0. So this must hold. Why I can't make Mathematica to confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

partial help:

this assumption

```
{a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i, j} > 0
```

does not apply seperately to each element, try this:

```
$Assumptions = Flatten[ { # > 0 & /@ {a, b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j} , 0 < a < 1 } ]
```

Also specifying > 0 implies reals so you dont need that explicit assumption.

Edit, part 2 of your problem is that Reduce doesnt even use $Assumptions, so you need to Simplify[] after reduce..  However even then you still dont get your answer. Consider this somewhat simplified example:

```
$Assumptions = Flatten[{# > 0 & /@ {a, b, c, f, g}, 0 < a < 1}]
res = Reduce[ (-1 + a)  (f + g) >= b c , {a, b, c, f, g}, Reals]  
(* huge output*)
Simplify[res ]
(* b c <= (-1 + a) (f + g) *)
```

Which should trivilaly shown to be False using the supplied assumptions. In fact this works..

```
Simplify[Reduce[ (-1 + a)  >= b c/(f + g) , {a, b, c, d, e, f, g},   Reals]  ]
(* False *)
```

Suggest you ask over on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/, or some moderator should migrate this..

Edit 3 -- I got it..

```
$Assumptions =  And @@ Flatten[{# > 0 & /@ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j},
                           0 < a < 1}] ;
Simplify[Reduce[ a (b c - (-1 + a) d (c + f g)) h > (-1 + a) i (b +  a j) g 
          && $Assumptions, {a, b, c, d,e,f, g, h, i, j}, Reals]]

(*True*)
```

Comment: Nice. Also didn't realize that there was a specific stackexchange for mathematica. Seems a bit inactive tough.